# VB.NET Get text in between Quotations or other symbols

Tags: vb.net, string

I want to be able to extract a string in between quotation marks or parenthesis etc. to a variable. For example my text might be "Hello there "Bob" ". I want to extract the text "Bob" from in between the two quotation marks and put it in the string "name" for later use. The same would be for "Hello there (Bob)". How would I go about this? Thanks.

=======EDIT======

Sorry, I worded this poorly. Ok, so lets say I have a textbox(Textbox1) and a button. If the user inputs the text: MsgBox "THIS IS MY MESSAGE" I want that when the Button is pressed, only the text THIS IS MY MESSAGE is displayed.

Comment: Did you mean that when the user inputted this `MsgBox "THIS IS MY MESSAGE"`? should be the result is `THIS IS MY MESSAGE`. please rephrase your question

Comment: so the user is actually inputted this words `MsgBox "THIS IS MY MESSAGE"`? and you want then to display this words `THIS IS MY MESSAGE` where?.

Comment: It would go to a variable which could then be used later (I.e to display the text in a messagebox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution very simple:

```
Dim sAux() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(""""c)
Dim sResult As String = ""

If sAux.Length = 3 Then
    sResult = sAux(1)
Else
    ' Error or something (number of quotes <> 2)
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

There are basically three methods -- regular expressions, string.indexof and substring and finally looping over the characters one by one.  I would avoid the latter as it is just reinventing the wheel.  Whether to use regexs or indexof depends upon the complexity of your requirements and data.  Indexof is a bit wordy but fairly straightforward and possibly just what you want in this case.

```
Dim str as String = "Hello there ""Bob"""
Dim startName as Integer 
Dim endName as Integer
Dim name as String = ""

startName = str.IndexOf("""")
endName = str.Indexof("""", If(startName > 0, startName,0))
If (endName>startName) Then
    name = str.SubString(startName, endName)
End If
```

If you need to do this for arbitrary symbols, then you want regexs.